# Not sure how to implement the SMB project into my app

Tags: swift, xcode, smb

I'm trying to implement SMB into my app and found this https://github.com/amosavian/AMSMB2. I'm not sure how to implement this code into the UI of my app. For example, do I connect the connect function to a button and if so how would I proceed to do so. What would I put into the parameters of connect() when I call it if I call it. 
Here's the code from the repository:

```
import AMSMB2

class SMBClient {
/// connect to: `smb://guest@XXX.XXX.XX.XX/share`

let serverURL = URL(string: "smb://XXX.XXX.XX.XX")!
let credential = URLCredential(user: "guest", password: "", persistence: URLCredential.Persistence.forSession)
let share = "share"

lazy private var client = AMSMB2(url: self.serverURL, credential: self.credential)!

private func connect(handler: @escaping (Result<AMSMB2, Error>) -> Void) {
    // AMSMB2 can handle queueing connection requests
    client.connectShare(name: self.share) { error in
        if let error = error {
            handler(.failure(error))
        } else {
            handler(.success(self.client))
        }
    }
}

func listDirectory(path: String) {
    connect { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let client):
            client.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let files):
                    for entry in files {
                        print("name:", entry[.nameKey] as! String,
                              ", path:", entry[.pathKey] as! String,
                              ", type:", entry[.fileResourceTypeKey] as! URLFileResourceType,
                              ", size:", entry[.fileSizeKey] as! Int64,
                              ", modified:", entry[.contentModificationDateKey] as! Date,
                              ", created:", entry[.creationDateKey] as! Date)
                    }

                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func moveItem(path: String, to toPath: String) {
    self.connect { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let client):
            client.moveItem(atPath: path, toPath: toPath) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                } else {
                    print("\(path) moved successfully.")
                }

                // Disconnecting is optional, it will be called eventually
                // when `AMSMB2` object is freed.
                // You may call it explicitly to detect errors.
                client.disconnectShare(completionHandler: { (error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                    }
                })
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

late but for reference as i couldnt find much when i tried

add the `amsmb2` library and that template class file to your project
in the class file set `serverurl`, share, credential correctly for your smb server

then
declare  a  variable of class `smb_client`
then from your button or whatever

```
var myclient:smb_client=smb_client()
myclient.connect()
```

to connect to your smb server for example
you can extend that class templete to download/upload items etc
the operations are asynchronous